# mysql query to calculate cricket batsman average

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table , which holds data like this.

```
Name    |how_out    |runs
------------------------------
Robin   |Not out    |45
Robin   |lbw        |25
Robin   |caught     |50
Robin   |caught     |0
Robin   |bowled     |30
Robin   |bowled     |0
.
.
.
```

I want one SQL query, which returns the following columns

Name , Total_runs , Average

Sounds simple enough, but the only problem for me is that. 
In cricket , average is just not Sum( runs)/count(*)
it's Sum(runs)/Count of number of innings where `how_out` is not 'Not out'

Could some one tell me how to write one such query ?

The query that i wrote gave the wrong average for obvious reasons.
The query that i wrote was

```
Select `Name`,sum(`runs`) as 'Total_runs', Sum(`runs`)/count(*)
From `batsman_stats`
group by `Name`
order by 2 desc
```

Could sql experts please help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select `Name`,sum(`runs`) as 'Total_runs', Sum(`runs`)/sum(if(how_out <> 'Not out',1,0))
From `batsman_stats`
group by `Name`
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: nice - you could if strip the IF(), `how_out <> 'Not out'` will evaluate 1 or 0.

Comment: Yes, I know. I wrote it in extended form to be easier to undestand. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a subselect:

```
Select Name, sum(runs) as Total_runs, Sum(runs)/(
   select count(*) from batsman_stats b
   where b.Name=a.Name and not b.how_out = 'Not out'
)
From batsman_stats a
group by Name
order by 2 desc
```

Answer (score 1):

[You could use a CASE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html):

```
SELECT Name,
       SUM(Runs) as Total_runs, 
       SUM(Runs)/COUNT(CASE WHEN how_out <> 'Not out' THEN 1 END) as Average
FROM batsman_stats
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY SUM(Runs) DESC
```